# move everything in html page down without changing the position of the videos

Tags: html, css, css-position, padding, positioning

I have created a page where there is a mask with a design over my whole page and videos play in the mask/ design. I want to make it so the top has more space, and everything is 100px down the page. When I change the "top from 50px, to 100px in .mask-wrapper, it is what I want it to look like, but then all my videos are not in the same place because I positioned them with "top=50px"

Is there anyway to move everything in the html page down and keep the same positioning?
Here is the link to the page

file:///Users/kelseyselby/Desktop/%20Semester%201%202018/Web%20Design%20Basics/keke13505.github.io/FINALPROJECT/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    </head>
    <body>


      <video loop id="ocean" src="video/OCEAN_8873.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
       <video id="vid" src="video/IMG_8873.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>


        <video loop id="cami" src="video/cami_8873.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>

      <video id="night-sv" src="video/night-sv.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>

      <div id="long">
       <video  id="sunsetmon" class="tik" src="video/sunsetmon.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
        <video id="coors" class="tik" src="video/coors.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <video loop id="dance" class="clips" src="video/dance.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
       <video loop id="coding" class="clips" src="video/coding.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
       <video loop id="tony" class="clips" src="video/tony.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
       <video loop id="fuck" class="clips"  src="video/fuck.mp4" type="video/mp4">  </video>
    </div>

    <audio id="music" autoplay loop src="video/hello.mp3" >
      <!-- <source   type="audio/mp3"> -->
    </audio>

    <div id="pop">
      <video loop id="mom" class="go" src="video/ice.mp4"></video>
    <video id="SVdark" class="go" src="video/ladrone.mp4"> </video>
    </div>


     <div id="group">
      <video loop id="laDrone" class="items" src="video/ladrone.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      <video loop id="snowangel" class="items" src="video/snowangel.mp4"></video>
      <video loop id="clash" class="items" src="video/coding.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      <video loop id="flash" class="items" src="video/coding.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      <video loop id="milan" class="items" src="video/milan.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      <video loop id="ice" class="items" src="video/ice.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
      <video loop id="amst" class="items" src="video/amst.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>

       <video loop id="jesus" src="video/jesus.mp4" type="video/mp4"> . 
   </video>

    <div id="flow">
        <video loop id="rainbow" class="drop" src="video/rainbow.mp4"> 
    </video>
        <video loop id="waterfall" class="drop" src="video/waterfall.mp4"> 
    </video>
        <video loop id="chill" class="drop" src="video/chill.mp4"> </video>
      </div>



     <!--  <video id="ice" src="video/ice.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
     -->





      <div class="mask-wrapper">
        <div class="mask">
          <div class="hole"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mask">
          <div class="hole"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mask">
          <div class="hole"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mask">
          <div class="hole"></div>
        </div> </div>

I actually have probably 500 of the "mask" "hole" divs to create a grid across the page 


CSS
    body {
          margin: 0;
          background-color: white: ;
          background-size: 400% 400%;

      }




    .mask-wrapper {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 600px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }



     .mask {
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          overflow: hidden;
          position: relative;
          border: 3px solid black;
        }


      .hole {
        border-radius: 100px;
        border: 5px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }


    #vid {
     position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
      top: 42px;
      left: 10px;
      opacity: 0;


    }



    #night-sv {
      position: absolute;
      width: 394px;
      height: 300px;
      right: 10px;
      top: 385px;
      opacity: 0;

    }

    #cami {
      position: absolute;
      width: 364px;
      top: 330px;
      left: 10px;
      opacity: 0;
    }


    #ocean {
      position: absolute;
      width: 1060px;
      height: 700px;
      right: 10px;
      opacity: 0;

    }

     .clips{
      position: relative;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      top: 502px;
      left: 18px;
      opacity: ;
      width: 203px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: -10px;
      opacity: 0;


    }

    #jesus {
      position: absolute;
      width: 297px;
      height: 200px;
      left: 513px;
      top: 37px;
      opacity: 0;

    }

    #laDrone {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      left: 362px;
      top: 52px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }

    #snowangel {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      left: 362px;
      top: 136px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }

    #flash {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      right: 568px;
      top: 600px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }

    #clash {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      right: 418px;
      top: 600px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }

    #ice {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      right: 404px;
      top: 600px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }

    #amst  {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      right: 496px;
      top: 600px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }

    #milan {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      right: 588px;
      top: 600px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }


    #coors {
      position: absolute;
      width: 211px;
      right: 10px;
      top: 50px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #sunsetmon {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      right: 105px;
      top: 50px;
      opacity:0  ;
    }

    #SVdark {
      position: absolute;
      width: 448px;
      left: 362px;
      top: 218px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #mom {
      position: absolute;
      width: 263px;
      right: 405px;
      top: 470px;
      opacity: 0;
    }



    #rainbow { 
      position: absolute;
      width: 352px;
      left: 10px;
      top: 210px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #waterfall { 
      position: absolute;
      width: 352px;
      left: 10px;
      top: 50px;
      opacity:0 ;
    }


    #chill { 
      position: absolute;
      width: 352px;
      left: 10px;
      top: 374px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .header body {
      height: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: We can't see files on your computer. Maybe link to a public url, or post a plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving top margin to the page

```
body {
   margin: 50px 0 0 0;
   background-color: white;
   background-size: 400% 400%;
}
```